# button is clicked when an option in a list is selected

Tags: button, select, input

I have a list of countries and depending of which country is chosen a shipping cost is calculated:

```html
<label for="country_shipping">
    country
</label>
<select required name='country_shipping' id="country_shipping" type="text">
    <option>
        <?php echo esc_html($country_shipping); ?>
    </option>
    <?php include "../auth/pages/countries_list.php" ?>
</select>
```

then I have a button that starts the calculation of the shipping cost once the user choose from the list:

```
<input type="submit" name="register"></input>
```

if I choose from the list and than I click on the button everything works fine; but how can I avoid the fact that I have to click on the button to start the calculation?
In other words, how can the fact that an option is chosen activate the button as someone clicked on it?

I tried different JavaScript solutions but nothing seems to work.

Comment: I found a slution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66621450/auto-submit-once-option-selected